# Benefits of alternative formulation of the integral (general measure)

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a measure space and $f:X\to \mathbb{R}^+$ a measurable map. Set

$$F(t) = \mu (\{x\in X \mid f(x)>t\})$$

and define

$$\int_X f\,d\mu := \int_0^\infty F(t)\,dt,$$

where the integral on the right is the Riemann integral. Since $F$ is monotonically decreasing, we know that the Riemann integral always exists (assuming the limit is finite).

Apparently, this definition agrees with the typical construction of the integral, where we define the integral for simple functions and then approximate from below the integral on the left with integrals of simple functions taking the supremum.

My question is the following: What is the advantage of this alternate definition? I realize that one can piggyback on results derived from the Riemann integral, but since the main goal is always to prove convergence theorems, does it actually help there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have probably been reading "Analysis" by Lieb & Loss, have you?

The main advantage that I see using that approach is that you can (seemingly) avoid a lot if overhead: You do not have to talk about simple functions (i.e. $\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \chi_{A_i}$), you do not have to show that each measurable nonnegative function is the monotone limit of a sequence of simple functions and you do not have to show that the integral is well-defined on simple functions, etc.

Thus, like the dark side of the force, it is "quicker, easier".

You can even prove the usual convergence theorems using this definition, as long as you believe/know/show that if $(f_n)$ is an increasing sequence of decreasing functions, then $\int f_n \, dx \to \int \lim f_n \, dx$ (the limit is Riemann integrable, because it is decreasing).

**But** if you want to show things like additivity of the integral, $\int f+g \, d\mu =\int f \,d\mu +\int g\, d\mu$, this is not easy at all. The path taken in Lieb & Loss (hidden in an exercise) is to approximate $f$ and $g$ by simple functions, so in the end one does not really gain anything.

Also, this new approach requires you to develop the Riemann integral beforehand, which I do not really like.

Comment: You got me. It's from Lieb & Loss. I noticed too that additivity was never proven. Since they also skip the definition of the Lebesgue integral, maybe they just want to get past the basics in as few pages as possible.

Comment: The dark side of the force is not only easier, but also has its charm. In this definition of integral charm is certainly missing: struggle with the construction of Riemann integral only to define Lebesgue one in a non-handy way.

Comment: @JT1: You mean, they are skipping the construction/definition of the Lebesgue **measure**, I suppose. One thing I wanted to add is that **knowing the formula** $\int f \, d\mu = \int_0^\infty F(t) \, dt$, or more generally $\int |f|^p \, d\mu = p \cdot \int_0^\infty t^{p-1} F(t) \, dt$ (where the integral on the right can also be interpreted as a Lebesgue integral) is useful. For example, the proof of the Marcinkiewicz interpolation theorem (certainly misspelled) is based on this. But using it for the definition of the integral has certain disadvantages as pointed out above.

Comment: Yes, I meant measure. Typo.